# Сравнение строк c модификатором final

Tags: java, строки, final

Подскажите пож-ста, почему модификатор final меняет результат сравнения?

```
String str4 = "socialmedia";

String str1 = "social";
String str2 = "media";
String str3 = str1 + str2;
System.out.println(str3 == str4); // false

final String str11 = "social";
final String str21 = "media";
String str31 = str11 + str21;
System.out.println(str31 == str4); // true
```

Answer (score 6):

При создании экземпляра класса String путем присваивания его ссылки
на литерал, последний помещается в так называемый «пул литералов». Если
в дальнейшем будет создана еще одна ссылка на литерал, эквивалентный ранее
объявленному, то будет произведена попытка добавления его в «пул литералов». Так как идентичный литерал там уже существует, то дубликат не может
быть размещен, и вторая ссылка будет на существующий литерал. 
Аналогично в случае, если литерал является вычисляемым. То есть компилятор воспринимает литералы "socialmedia" и "social" + "media" как эквивалентные.
В данном случае слияние финализированных строк в String str31 = str11 + str21; это то же самое что и String str31 = "social" + "media". 
В итоге str31 будет ссылатся на ту же самую область «пула литералов» что и String str4 = "socialmedia";

А т.к. String str3 = str1 + str2; (слияние нефинализированных ссылок) то эта переменная уже не попадет в  «пул литералов» и сравнение ссылок приведет к false.

Comment: да, норм ответ, но лучше пул строк называть пулом строк, а не пулом литералов, тк там могут быть не только литералы

Comment: нет, там хранятся только литералы

Comment: там хранятся литералы и всё, что добавил программист методом .intern().

Comment: @Maxgmer а Вы попробуйте добавить не литерал методом .intern()

Comment: Т.е. String str3 = str1 + str2; попадает в "кучу"?

Comment: @AndreyZinovich попробовал, получилось, хотя и пробовать нечего было, дока джавы не врет, можете не надеяться) Вот, попробуйте, даст true без final  `String a = "a";
    String b = "b";
    String c = "c";
    System.out.print((a + b + c).intern() == "abc");`

Comment: @Maxgmer ну так вы же литералы добавили в пул, никаких проблем не будет.

Comment: @tilgiz да, String str3 будет ссылатся на кучу.

Comment: @AndreyZinovich всё ясно, дальше нечего спорить, если (a + b + c) для вас литерал

Comment: @Maxgmer читайте внимательнее, я писал что вы помещаете литералЫ методом .intern()

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз когда мы создаем **не final** строки путем конкатенации, то мы создаем новый объект, который будет положен в heap. Если мы захотим, чтобы результат первого сравнения (str3 == str4) был true, то нам надо на str3 использовать intern(), тогда java увидит, что такая строка в string pool уже есть (str4) и вернет ссылку на нее.

Однако, когда мы указываем у строки **final**, то java может произвести ***оптимизацию на стадии компиляции***. Рас уж str11 ("social") и str21 ("media") объявлены как final, то эти ссылки всегда будут указывать на одну и ту же область памяти. Это, конечно, не значит, что сам объект, на который мы ссылаемся не может измениться, но рас уж у нас речь о String (иммутабельном классе, который вшит в JRE), то за это можно не беспокоиться. А значит и конкатенация final строк даст гарантированный результат, который будет оптимизирован и автоматически отправлен в string pool.

```
String str1 = "social"; // Изменяемая ссылка
String str2 = "media"; // Изменяемая ссылка
String str3 = str1 + str2; // Здесь компилятор еще не знает точных значений str1 и str2,
str1 = "qwe"; // ведь мы в любой момент можем изменить то,
str2 = "123"; // на что ссылаются str1 и str2.

final String str11 = "social"; // Неизменяемая ссылка
final String str21 = "media";  // Неизменяемая ссылка
String str31 = str11 + str21;  // Получаем гарантированный неизменяемый результат.
str11 = "java"; // Попытка изменить final строку приведет к ошибке.
```

Это чем то похоже на раннее связывание, но в контексте полей.